# get all entries by column name: HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table of the following format:-

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| name | subject1 | subject2 | subject3 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| xxx  | pass     | fail     | pass     |
| yyy  | pass     | pass     | pass     |
| zzz  | pass     | fail     | fail     |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The table is dynamically created with json data obtained from the server. I create every  with name tag containing the names of the subject since the number of subjects are not constant. Now, what I want to do is have lists corresponding to subjects.. say subject1[],2 and so on and these lists will contain the list of pass/fails associated with that subject... I can then compute the number of pass/fails for that subjects and draw graphs.

While I am aware that this:can be used to get all rows for a particular column,

```
$('#mytable tbody td:nth-col(4)')
```

This wont be useful if the number of columns are fixed.
Kindly let me know how to accomplish this using jquery/JS.
**EDIT:**
data.json:-(if parsing can be done)

```
{"students": [{"student": John, "status": "pass", "subject": "english"},{"student": Joe, "status": "pass", "subject": "english"},{"student": Jill, "status": "fail", "subject": "french"}]}
```

Comment: Did you mean `nth-child(4)`? Also, you're saying the table is created based on JSON data, why not extract the necessary peace from the data instead of relying on the DOM?

Comment: But my json data is of a complicated format.. Can i post it here?

Comment: Yes. I think it may lead us to the best answer.

Comment: What is the expected format of the results? `{ "english": { "passed": ["John", "Joe"], "failed": [] }, "french": { "passed": [], "failed": ["Jill"] } }`? (http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/68b3e5)

Comment: No I need JS lists that look like. english=[pass,fail,pass], french=[fail,pass] etc..  So in json they must look like {"english":[pass,fail,pass],"french":[pass,pass,fail]} so i can easily compute the count of passes and fails in each subject.

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/e9xro3sc/ what you're looking for?

Comment: Partially yes. It would be helpful if there is a way to compute the number of pass/fails since that'd be the precise answer.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/e9xro3sc/1/ then

Comment: Please update your fiddle in the answers. I accept it :)

Comment: But one small idea. I dont want the results in json format

Comment: So, what is the expected format?

Comment: I just need javascript dictionary like format. var subject[english]={pass:10,fail:10}.. But your json will also do. Kindly update your comments in an answer. Its brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it will be much easier to aggregate the data from the original source (which is a JavaScript object in this case) rather than extracting it from its visual representation (the DOM in this case).

To group the data based on the `subject` of each student data:

```
var res = {};

for (var i in data.students)
{
    var item = data.students[i];
    var subject = item.subject;

    if (!res[subject])
        res[subject] = { passedCount: 0, failedCount: 0 };

    if (item.status == 'pass')
        res[subject].passedCount++;
    else
        res[subject].failedCount++;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9xro3sc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

> I create every with name tag containing the names of the subject

As you're mentioning the name tag in all the elements you create, you can use the following selector:

```
$("[name='subject1']")
```

This will return you all elements which contains subject1 in its name attribute.

Instead of `name` attribute, if you use `data-subject` and store the subject name in that particular cell, then

```
$("[data-subject='subject1']")
```

This will return you all cells containing subject1.